# Understanding RSpec Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

I'm getting these failures when running `rspec spec/`. The spec that is failing is was auto-generated with the scaffolding. I'm trying to understand RSpec but I don't know where to begin looking for the cause other than it *feels* like *some* method is missing?!? Yet, app appears to be working fine. Nothing about these failures appears in `test.log`. Is there another place I should be looking for hints to track this down?

```
$ rspec spec/
.....................F.F.

Failures:

  1) clowns/edit.html.haml renders the edit clown form
     Failure/Error: render
     undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/clowns/_form.html.haml:4:in `block in _app_views_clowns__form_html_haml__3590088286240866241_2176114460_3896491916910336970'
     # ./app/views/clowns/_form.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_clowns__form_html_haml__3590088286240866241_2176114460_3896491916910336970'
     # ./app/views/clowns/edit.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_clowns_edit_html_haml___574620942879655923_2176081980_599706797287605391'
     # ./spec/views/clowns/edit.html.haml_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) clowns/new.html.haml renders new clown form
     Failure/Error: render
     undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/clowns/_form.html.haml:4:in `block in _app_views_clowns__form_html_haml__3590088286240866241_2176114460_3896491916910336970'
     # ./app/views/clowns/_form.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_clowns__form_html_haml__3590088286240866241_2176114460_3896491916910336970'
     # ./app/views/clowns/new.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_clowns_new_html_haml__1085372210838170129_2159651900_599706797287605391'
     # ./spec/views/clowns/new.html.haml_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.03 seconds
27 examples, 2 failures, 2 pending
```

And here is the spec that apparently fails (`edit.html.haml_spec.rb`). It was auto-generated by `rails g scaffold Clown name:string balloons:integer`:

```
#spec/views/clowns/edit.html.haml_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "clowns/edit.html.haml" do
  before(:each) do
    @clown = assign(:clown, stub_model(Clown,
      :name => "MyString",
      :balloons => 1
    ))
  end

  it "renders the edit clown form" do
    render

    # Run the generator again with the --webrat-matchers flag if you want to use webrat matchers
    assert_select "form", :action => clown_path(@clown), :method => "post" do
      assert_select "input#clown_name", :name => "clown[name]"
      assert_select "input#clown_balloons", :name => "clown[balloons]"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you also using **simple_form** (or perhaps even **formtastic**)?  I get the same error when I convert the scaffold forms from standards forms to simple_form forms (`form_for(@user)` => `simple_form_for(@user)`).

It still works, as you say, so I'm not sure it's worth worrying about.  I think you'd be better off just letting Cucumber worry about it.  Sarah Mei says [view specs are a waste of time](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2010/05/29/outside-in-bdd/). :-)